# Symfony 2.3 Entity Boolean Property Allow Only One Row to be True

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, entity

This should be pretty easy, but I can't seem to find the answer...
What I'm trying to do is create a page bundle; that parts been pretty easy. I've added an `isHome` column to my database. Basically I want that to set a flag on the page that is the home page. Obviously, only one row in the database can have that value set to true, the rest need to be false.

Let's say for the moment that I don't care if ALL records are false, I just want, at the most, one record to be true (although it would be nice to force at least one record to be true).

The way I originally thought about doing this is creating a method in the repository to set all `isHome` values to false if the current `page` object set the `isHome` value to true, then save that record. Seemed like a good idea, but it appears I can't/shouldn't call the repository from the entity.

Any ideas on how I can allow only one record to have `isHome` set to true from the entity?

I'm using Symfony 2.3.1 with a MySQL database and doctrine2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a PrePersist and PreUpdate doctrine [listener/subscriber](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#listening-and-subscribing-to-lifecycle-events) for your entity.

When the listener is triggered query your repository for other entities with isHome set to true using something like `findBy(array('isHome' => true))` ...

... then update all found entities with isHome false and there will always be only one left being home after you persisted/updated your entity.

Comment: That was perfect! The only issue I had was that when I tried to flush() the update for the other rows, it was calling the preUpdate event again. So it just kept going in circles. Finally, I found that a DQL query didn't call the preUpdate/prePersist events and used that instead. It seems to work perfectly now. Thanks!